# how to use a variable in in an object in a javascript class

Tags: javascript, node.js, oop

How do I make `foo()` work?

file1.js:

```js
module.exports = class Example{

    constructor(something){
        
        this.something = something
    }

    functions ={

        foo(){

            return this.something
        }
    }
}
```

file2.js:

```js
const Example = require('./file1.js')
const object = new Example("among")

console.log(object.foo())
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

First: you have to access those functions via `.functions` since that's where they live

Second, `this` will not be correct, so you can either

- Make `foo` an arrow function
- or you can `.bind(this)` to a function - like with `bar` in this code
- you can't use `.bind` when using function property shorthand though - i.e. `foo() { return this.something }.bind(this)` - but you can bind it in the `constructor`

See the code for all three solutions - and why you need to bind the non arrow functions

```js
class Example{
    constructor(something){
        this.something = something;
        // bat needs to be bound here
        this.functions.bat = this.functions.bat.bind(this);
    }
    functions ={
        // "this" will be correct here
        foo: () => this.something,
        // bar needs to be bound to "this"
        bar: function() { return this.something }.bind(this),
        // you can't bind a shorthand property function though
        bat() { return this.something },
        // this is what happens with no bind
        baz() { return this.something },
    }
    
}

const object = new Example("among")

console.log('foo', object.functions.foo())
console.log('bar', object.functions.bar())
console.log('bat', object.functions.bat())
console.log('baz', object.functions.baz())
```

Comment: i will set this as the answer when ill be able to

Answer (score 1):

Remove `functions`:

```js
class Example{

    constructor(something){
        this.something = something;
    }

    foo(){

        return this.something
    }
}

const object = new Example("among")

console.log(object.foo())
```

Comment: is there no other way? i wanted to group similiar functions like lets say logging functions in log

Comment: yea i just saw and deleted the previous comment